# How to run a package from development database on production database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a package on my development database called PAYE. I want to run the package from my development database on my production database.

I haven't tried anything yet because I have no clue where to start.

Let's take for example, If I'm changing the status of a column to processed in my PAYE table then the changes in the status should be reflected in the production database and not on the development database when running the PAYE package.

Comment: This is possible. However it is a really bad idea, you should NEVER be updating data in a production database from a development database.  It is begging for trouble, if someone does changes to this and tests it, you could destroy your production data.

Comment: Use Datapump to export your production data and import it into non-production, and then test there. That's how you do it. Or do a full RMAN clone of your production database.